# How to send info from two session variable to a text file if a number has been guessed

Tags: php, arrays, file, session, session-variables

I'm stuck and I would be happy to get some guidance.

I need to send information from **two** session variables in the same session to a text file.

**Number of guesses:**  `$_SESSION['antal_gaet']`

**Username:**           `$_SESSION['username']`

How do I write to a textfile so that I can make a highscore list from the array with (number of guesses, username).

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Welcome to [so] Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create/open a new file then write in it the concatenation of your variables:

```
$scores_file = 'scores.txt';
// open the file
$handle = fopen($scores_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$scores_file);
// create 1rst line and a line feed \n
$data = 'Number of guesses:'.$_SESSION['antal_gaet']."\n";
// concat the 2nd line
$data .= 'Username:'.$_SESSION['username'];
// write to the opened file
fwrite($handle, $data);
```

Comment: Side note: *"I took the opportunity to fix an obvious error. The \n in single quotes will not parse; it requires double quotes. Please be more careful next time, thank you."* - Is the note I left in the edit I made.